# Radio Button doesn't find clicked method

Tags: java, android, radio-button, radio-group

My Radio buttons wont find the clicked method which is onRadioButtonClicked. The method says that it is never used and when I try the radioButton the application crashes because there is no onRadioButtonClicked method.

```
<RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rbTerrorist"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                android:text="Terrorist" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rbCounterTerrorist"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                android:text="Counter-Terrorist" />
        </RadioGroup>

 public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
        // Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.rbTerrorist:
                if (checked)
                    // Pirates are the best
                    break;
            case R.id.rbCounterTerrorist:
                if (checked)
                    // Ninjas rule
                    break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should be using an `OnCheckedChangeListener` on the `RadioGroup` instead.

Comment: Sorry Peter, making an application for Counter-Strike: Global offensive

Comment: But what would that matter if I use `OnCheckedChangeListener` Just a different method name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you should be using for `RadioButton`s and `RadioGroup` is [OnCheckedChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener.html)

use this method

```
    RadioGroup rb = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.your_Radio_group_id);
    rb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.rbTerrorist:
                    // to task                                         
                    break;
                case R.id.rbCounterTerrorist:
                    // to task                                         
                    break;
            }
        }

    });
```